# Susy 2 and Breakpoint

Tags: susy, susy-sass, breakpoint-sass

I am finally transitioning over to Susy 2 from Susy One and have been struggling a bit with the new syntax. Specifically, using it with the Breakpoint mixin.

In Susy One, I had this:

```css
// Mobile First Settings

.grid-construct{
  $total-columns: $bp-sm-columns;
  $column-width: $bp-sm-column-width;
  $gutter-width: $bp-sm-gutter-width;
  $grid-padding: $bp-sm-grid-padding;
  $container-width: $bp-sm-container-width;
  $container-style: $bp-sm-container-style;

  @include container; 
}


//for medium devices

@include breakpoint($breakpoint-md) {
  .grid-construct {
    $total-columns: $bp-md-columns;
    $grid-padding: $bp-md-grid-padding;

    @include container;
  }
}


// large devices

@include breakpoint($breakpoint-lg) {
  .grid-construct {
    $total-columns: $bp-lg-columns;
    $grid-padding: $bp-lg-grid-padding;

    @include container;
  }
}
```

I was then able to write styles such as:

```css
.my-style{
  margin-top: 10px;

  @include breakpoint($breakpoint-md) {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }

  @include breakpoint($breakpoint-lg) {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}
```

An example of my HTML markup:

```html
<div class="grid-construct">
  <div class="my-style">
    Lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this pattern portable to Susy 2? Would I need to make 3 individual `$susy` maps for my 3 respective breakpoints?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Your second example (`.my-style`) is completely un-affected by your initial settings. Because Sass is un-aware of the DOM, variables set inside breakpoints wont remain set across similar breakpoints. But, in any case, the second example doesn't use Susy at all. What is the first example meant to accomplish besides changing the size of the outer container?

Comment: @EricMSuzanne In the 2nd example `.my-style` is nested within `.grid-construct` which is affected by Susy and `@include container`. I have edited the markup to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the only thing changing at the different breakpoints is the size of the container based on number of total columns (Susy 2 doesn't have `grid-padding` because you can add that easily yourself). If you set up the basic `$susy` map the way you want it, you can use the [shorthand](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/shorthand/) to override that as you go:

```
.grid-construct {
  @include container;

  @include breakpoint($breakpoint-md) {
    max-width: container($bp-md-columns);
  }

  @include breakpoint($breakpoint-lg) {
    max-width: container($bp-lg-columns);
  }
}
```

(I used the `container` function because that max-width is all you really need to override)

You can also use `susy-breakpoint` to change the settings for the entire breakpoint block:

```
@include susy-breakpoint($breakpoint-lg, $bp-lg-columns) {
  @include container;
}
```